# Click detection outside A conditioned HTML element - Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a custom select that appears conditionally in the DOM.
I trying to detect the user clicks outside the element and remove the element from the DOM. Better i show you what appears to be the problem

**HTML**

```
 <div class="worker-info">
        <div (click)="showWorkersSelect = !showWorkersSelect" class="worker-name">
            <fa-icon [icon]="['fal', 'user-circle']" size="1x"></fa-icon>
            Worker name: <span>Anna</span>
            <fa-icon  class="select-worker-icon" [icon]="['fal', 'caret-down']" size="1x"></fa-icon>
        </div>

        <div #workerSelection @showWorkersSelect *ngIf="showWorkersSelect" class="select-worker-menu">
            <div  (click)="showWorkersSelect = !showWorkersSelect" class="select-worker-menu__worker-name">
              Essti
            </div>
            <div  (click)="showWorkersSelect = !showWorkersSelect"class="select-worker-menu__worker-name">
               Ilana
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So when the user clicks here

```
 <div (click)="showWorkersSelect = !showWorkersSelect" class="worker-name">
```

The `showWorkersSelect` becoming `true` and the selection appers.

**TS**

```
  @ViewChild('workerSelection') workerSelection: ElementRef
  public showWorkersSelect = false

      @HostListener('document:click', ['$event', '$event.target'])
      onClick(event: MouseEvent, targetElement: HTMLElement): void {
        if (this.showWorkersSelect) {
          if (!targetElement) {
            return;
          }
          const clickedInside = this.workerSelection.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
          if (!clickedInside) {
              this.showWorkersSelect = false;
          }
        }
      }
```

Here I want to run the method only when the selection is shown and close it after the user clicks outside, but the method closing it immediately after it opens

Answer (score 0):

If your worker-selection has a z-index>0, You can use a "div" between with a z-index between 0 and z-index of worker-selection that cover all the screen

```
<div class="backscreen" *ngIf="showWorkersSelect" (click)="showWorkersSelect=false">

.backscreen {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1040; //<--use a z-index between 0 and z-index of selectWorker
    background-color: transparent;
}
```